# How to get week start and week end in excel for given month only

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As I was new to excel, I am working on a use case where I want to get week start and week end dates of a given month,
I am using following formulae which is giving me next month date followed by weekend.

```
=A7+(6-WEEKDAY(A7,2)+1)


Week Start  Week End
7/1/18  7/1/18
7/2/18  7/8/18
7/9/18  7/15/18
7/16/18 7/22/18
7/23/18 7/29/18
7/30/18 8/5/18
```

How can I modify or have a new formulae which gives me month end date, if my weekend is on next month

Expected output should be

```
Week Start  Week End
7/1/18  7/1/18
7/2/18  7/8/18
7/9/18  7/15/18
7/16/18 7/22/18
7/23/18 7/29/18
7/30/18 7/31/18
```

For month like Feb as it is unable to caluculate the formula it should return 0

```
Week Start  Week End
2/1/18  2/4/18
2/5/18  2/11/18
2/12/18 2/18/18
2/19/18 2/25/18
2/26/18 2/28/18
1/0/00  1/1/00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wrap the result of your original formula in MIN and compare it to EOMONTH.

```
=MIN(A7+(6-WEEKDAY(A7,2)+1), EOMONTH(A7, 0))
```

As far as Feb goes, you need to compare te current value with the one either above or below to determine whether *month(date)<>month(date+7)* and you have not shown enough of how your data structure transcends months to do that.

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for.. Thanks